# Module to Create Historic Timeline Snapshots of Drupal Sites?

Tags: staging

I'm looking for a module to create a functionality where it will take snapshots of the entire site and then replicate it to another domain/sub-domain every X number of days or weeks. I want to do this so I can go visit a previous version of the site in the past to see what was changed. I know you can do this with the module "demo", but that just takes a snapshot of the DB and you would have to revert back to that time overwriting what you currently have. Yes I can create a staging server for this, but I want to be able to have it done automatically where I have the following sub-domains where i can go back to:

1day-ago.foo.com
2day-ago.foo.com
1week-ago.foo.com
1month-ago.foo.com
2month-ago.foo.com
3month-ago.foo.com

How would this be done? Or is there a module for something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [Aegir](http://www.aegirproject.org/). Although it is more than a module, it has the functionality you describe. Basically what Aegir can do for you is create a complete copy (database, codebase and files) of your Drupal website. The catch here is that your Drupal site should be managed by Aegir as well.

On the more technical side, if you take a look at what Aegir does, you will notice that creating a copy of your website is performed by a number of drush scripts. These scripts could of course be used/modified to make your snapshots.